# Cloned Laravel project image not uploading

Tags: laravel, git

I cloned and install laravel project from git, also i had to copy `.env` file from fresh laravel project because git ignored env file when I pushed it amd connected successfully with database.

Everything working fine but image not uploading
.
Here is the pictures

[dd result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYxPM.jpg)
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIJgZ.jpg)

Comment: run php artisan storage:link

Comment: I tried this one too,  but it says, link already exists...

Comment: what does your laravel.log say. you can find this under storage>logs.

Comment: 1) try to log the ''request" before saving the data to database. 2) Check if you have image entry  in your fillable feild in modal